# Match words in multiple lines in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I want to write a spamassassin rule to catch spam. This rule would find some bad words that appears in mail. For example this is an email:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec
>   vehicula nec eros et consectetur. Integer iaculis consectetur nisi sed
>   feugiat. Praesent accumsan ipsum ac ante porttitor, ut fringilla
>   libero venenatis. Sed porttitor imperdiet dignissim. Integer
>   consectetur, nulla eu aliquet elementum, nisl lectus lobortis nisi, in
>   pretium sem dui in ligula.

Text is in six newlines. And the bad words is "imperdiet", "iaculis" and "nec". I was writing a rule:

```
/(?=.*imperdiet)(?=.*iaculis)(?=.*nec)/im
```

But this is not working. Its work only when bad words are in one line.
How to match across whole string?

Comment: The modifier you need is s not m. s allows the dot to match newlines. Another thing, you don't need to put all in lookaheads, use a simple alternation: `\b(?:word1|word2|...)\b` with word boundaries.

Comment: Have you looked at other spamassassin rules to see how they implement their regexes?  Surely there must be existing rules that do roughly the same thing as you're trying to implement that you could adapt.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte your rules doesn't work
      rawbody PROGRAM_SPAM /\b(?:niemiecki|program)\b/si
doesn't catch at all

Comment: If you want to handle underscores you can replace word-boundaries with lookarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vks and @hwnd for show me how to write right this rule

```
/(?=.*imperdiet)(?=.*iaculis)(?=.*nec)/si
```

It's works :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(?=[\s\S]*imperdiet)(?=[\s\S]*iaculis)(?=[\s\S]*nec)
```

You can try this way .It does not need a modifier.Or else you can also use modifier `s` ==> `DOTALL`

Comment: what's the point of this when you can simply type `s` after the ending delimiter? `/(?=.*imperdiet)(?=.*iaculis)(?=.*nec)/si`

Comment: All of yours propositions are ineffective :(

Comment: @vks I'm sorry. Yes its work. My spamassassin on laptop is broken (or something). But on server is working perfectly :) But I'm using `/(?=.*imperdiet)(?=.*iaculis)(?=.*nec)/si` notation. It's simpler.